# Assign cascaded IDs in dynamically nested elements (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, nested, dynamically-generated

I'm working on a script that dynamically generates 3 different components to build a grid: section -> row -> module. Now I'm working on the update function which should be able to update the IDs of each element present in the grid right after a new component is created:

```
function Update() {

    // Define components variables
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('#canvas [data-component="section"]');
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#canvas [data-component="row"]');
    var modules = document.querySelectorAll('#canvas [data-component="module"]');

    /**
     * Assign IDs to each existing section, row and module
     */
    // If there are sections...
    if ( sections.length > 0 ) {

        for ( var x = 0; x < sections.length; x++ ) {

            sectionNum = x + 1; 
            sections[x].id = 'component-' + sectionNum;

            // If there are rows...
            if ( rows.length > 0 ) {

                for ( var y = 0; y < rows.length; y++ ) {

                    // If this row is a descendant of that section...
                    if ( rows[y].parentElement.parentElement == sections[x] ) {

                        rowNum = y + 1; 
                        rows[y].id = 'component-' + sectionNum + '-' + rowNum;

                        // If there are modules...
                        if ( modules.length > 0 ) {

                            for ( var z = 0; z < modules.length; z++ ) {

                                // If this module is a descendant of that row...
                                if ( modules[z].parentElement.parentElement == rows[y] ) {

                                    moduleNum = z + 1;
                                    modules[z].id = 'component-' + sectionNum + '-' + rowNum + '-' + moduleNum;
                                };
                            };

                            // If the loop has reached the end, reset the index and break
                            if ( modules.length - 1 === z ) { z = 0; break };
                        };
                    };

                    // If the loop has reached the end, reset the index and break
                    if ( rows.length - 1 === y ) { y = 0; break; };
                };
            };

            // If the loop has reached the end, reset the index and break
            if ( sections.length - 1 === x ) { x = 0; break; };
        };
    };
};
```

I feel I'm pretty close to finish it, but I've been struggling trying to find the way to generate the output that I need.

This is what I'm getting at the moment:

```
#component-1
    #component-1-1
        #component-1-1-1
        #component-1-1-2
    #component-1-2
        #component-1-2-3
        #component-1-2-4
#component-2
    #component-2-3
        #component-2-3-5
        #component-2-3-6
    #component-2-4
        #component-2-4-7
        #component-2-4-8
```

But I need to reset the row and module number on each new section, like this:

```
#component-1
    #component-1-1
        #component-1-1-1
        #component-1-1-2
    #component-1-2
        #component-1-2-1
        #component-1-2-2
#component-2
    #component-2-1
        #component-2-1-1
        #component-2-1-2
    #component-2-2
        #component-2-2-1
        #component-2-2-2
```

Any ideas will be more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I end up answering my own question :P In case it might be helpful to someone else out there here it goes.

First of all, here's the final code:

```
/**
 * Update Components
 */
function Update() {

    /**
     * Assign IDs to each section, row and module
     */
    // Grab the sections contained in the canvas
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('#canvas [data-component="section"]');

    if ( sections.length > 0 ) {

        for ( var x = 0; x < sections.length; x++ ) {

            // Increase num by 1 to avoid "0" as first index
            var sectionNum = x + 1;

            // Assign an ID to the current section
            sections[x].id = 'component-' + sectionNum;

            // Grab the rows contained in this section
            var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#' + sections[x].id + ' [data-component="row"]');

            if ( rows.length > 0 ) {

                for ( var y = 0; y < rows.length; y++ ) {

                    // Increase num by 1 to avoid "0" as first index
                    var rowNum = y + 1;

                    // Assign an ID to the current row
                    rows[y].id = 'component-' + sectionNum + '-' + rowNum;

                    // Grab the modules contained in this row
                    var modules = document.querySelectorAll('#' + rows[y].id + ' [data-component="module"]');

                    if ( modules.length > 0 ) {

                        for ( var z = 0; z < modules.length; z++ ) {

                            // Increase num by 1 to avoid "0" as first index
                            var moduleNum = z + 1;
                            // Assign ID to module
                            modules[z].id = 'component-' + sectionNum + '-' + rowNum + '-' + moduleNum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ended up defining the variables for the rows and the modules in its previous loop and that finally did the trick (defined the rows variable inside the sections loop, and the modules variable inside the rows loop). If you're wondering why, it's because doing it this way I was able to use the current parent's ID to limit the search to the children contained by that particular parent, and then restart the count when a new parent is being looped.

This is minor detail, but I also removed the loop variable resets at the end of each loop, which were not even necessary.

And as a plus, here's the same thing in jQuery:

```
/**
 * Update Components
 */
function Update() {

    /**
     * Assign IDs to each section, row and module
     */
    // Grab the sections contained in the canvas
    var sections = $('#canvas [data-component="section"]');

    if ( sections.length > 0 ) {

        $(sections).each( function(x) {

            // Increase num by 1 to avoid "0" as first index
            var sectionNum = x + 1;

            // Assign an ID to the current section
            $(this).attr('id', 'component-' + sectionNum);

            // Grab the rows contained in this section
            var thisSectionID = this.id;
            var rows = $('#' + thisSectionID).find('[data-component="row"]');

            if ( rows.length > 0 ) {

                $(rows).each( function(y) {

                    // Increase num by 1 to avoid "0" as first index
                    var rowNum = y + 1;

                    // Assign an ID to the current row
                    $(this).attr('id', 'component-' + sectionNum + '-' + rowNum);

                    // Grab the modules contained in this row
                    var thisRowID = this.id;
                    var modules = $('#' + thisRowID).find('[data-component="module"]');

                    if ( rows.length > 0 ) {

                        $(modules).each( function(z) {

                            // Increase num by 1 to avoid "0" as first index
                            var moduleNum = z + 1;

                            // Assign an ID to the current module
                            $(this).attr('id', 'component-' + sectionNum + '-' + rowNum + '-' + moduleNum);
                        });
                    };
                });
            };
        });
    };
```

Hope it helps someone out there! :)